# Why am I getting the error "nets with possible connection problems" on my ground pins in Altium?

Tags: altium, error

Can somebody please explain why I am getting errors on my ground pins when connecting to a GND port?

[image]

As you can see the pins are defined as POWER type. The error is "Nets with possible connection problems", whatever that means. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens at pin 28 if you break the connection between pins 27 and 28?

Comment: @jsotola If I break the link, pin 28 is still connected to GND and still gives the error. The other pins that arent connected to GND but are still connected to each other show no error. Until I connect them to GND again then the error reappears. Thx for the clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define all your power pins (GND included) as **Passive**. This will get rid of the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it. I had read in another question that you should use Power for power and ground for some reason, https://forum.kicad.info/t/please-explain-electrical-type-when-create-new-ic-pin/742/3

Comment: And also in the last post here. Confusing. https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/question-about-starting-to-use-altium-to-create-the-microcontroller/

Comment: @TripleAntigen Problem with Altium, they only have *Power* as a pin type and don't differentiate between a power input or output. This ends up as a mess with Altium's DRC which is why I define power & ground pins  as passive.

Answer (score 1):

Look really really close where your wires touch your pins.

Clue... they don't.

There's a very very small gap there.

After you zoom in and fix it, set your grid to 10 or 100.  You have it set to '1'

Use the g hotkey to toggle it

Comment: Thanks but they were connected, the white bits are some graphical artifact of the four tiny pin dots. It goes away if you zoom.

Comment: By setting those pins as 'passive' you've defeated the error check.  Maybe it is a graphical anomaly, but I've been using Altium for a couple decades, and have seen this over & over (I administer it for our company).   That graphic looks JUST LIKE it would if your IC were off grid 1 tick.   I mean, I'm not there to wiggle the component and wires myself, but I'd have bet a lunch on this.  You'll know if you've got the right connections you push this to PCB layout ... the actual netlist will become obvious.

Comment: Setting the pin to "GND" or "POWER" tells Altium those pins should connect to power or gnd (duh).  It's flagging them because they don't.  It might be your gnd symbol that's off grid... looks like it's a tick or two lower than the connecting wire.

Comment: Although this wasn't the solution for this particular case, I have had this problem before with respect to the grid on the schematic editor. Since this might still help someone else with a similar problem, I recommend against deleting this answer (if you were remotely inclined to do so).

Comment: @KyleB Thanks again for the feedback but the pins were definitely connected. I could drag the component and the wires going to the pins would stretch along with it, same with the vertical wire coming from GND. Also in PCB the nets were present. I have had the mentioned issue before when using metric symbols on imperial sheets and vice versa but this was not the same problem.

Comment: @KyleB Also you mentioned "Setting the pin to "GND" or "POWER", but there is no pin type of GND. From Altiums website: "Available types are: Input, I/O, Output, Open Collector, Passive, HiZ, Open Emitter, and Power."  https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-dlg-schcomponentpinspropertiesformcomponent-pin-editor-ad?version=21  The closest of that lot is POWER and it gives errors when I connect them to GND (for me).

Comment: @TripleAntigen    right-click on the wires.  You'll get a popup that indicates what NET they are assigned to.  If they are not 'GND' that will explain it.  If that's the case, just delete and redraw them so they take the right net name.

Comment: ^^^   You're right BTW, there's only 'power' pins... not one you can assign to GND.   I use several programs  LOL  I didn't have Altium open at the time to verify.   Regardless, the concept is still unchanged.  You've got 'power' pins connecting to a non-power net.   You verified you can drag the IC and the wires follow - But what if you drag the GND symbol there?  Is that connected also???

Comment: @KyleB Yes, they are definitely connected to GND in the PCB too.